# Fluid design and position absolute

Tags: css, position

This is a fluid design of four images (width = 160px) with ul or floated divs.
 
Everything is well when resizing window. It's fluid.

But when I pass to an absolute position, I find no more 160px initially.

You can see the problem here http://jsfiddle.net/zXDH9/

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body { position:relative; }
        .container {
            /* remove comment to view problem */
            /*position:absolute; left:0; top:0;*/
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: black 1px solid;
            max-width: 690px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .galleryItem {
            float: left;
            width: 23%;
            margin: 0 1%;
            padding: 1% 0;
        }
        .galleryItem img { max-width: 100%; }
        ul { list-style: none; }
        ul.thumbs  {
            /* remove comment to view problem */
            /*position: absolute; left:0; top: 100px;*/
            display: block;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: black 1px solid;
            max-width:690px; overflow: hidden;
        }
        ul.thumbs>li {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            width: 23%;
            margin: 0 1%;
            padding: 1% 0;
        }
        ul.thumbs>li img {
            display: block;
            max-width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="galleryItem"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.e-business.tn/focus/images/galleria/hobs/thumbs/F.801X_mini.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div class="galleryItem"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.e-business.tn/focus/images/galleria/hobs/thumbs/F.802X_mini.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div class="galleryItem"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.e-business.tn/focus/images/galleria/hobs/thumbs/F.801W_mini.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="thumbs">
        <li class=""><a href="#"><img src="http://www.e-business.tn/focus/images/galleria/hobs/thumbs/F.801X_mini.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#"><img src="http://www.e-business.tn/focus/images/galleria/hobs/thumbs/F.802X_mini.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#"><img src="http://www.e-business.tn/focus/images/galleria/hobs/thumbs/F.801W_mini.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js">/*jQuery 1.5.1 Supports IE9, but not 1.5.0*/</script>
    <script>
        $(function(){ // Document is ready
            /*alert($('ul.thumbs').outerWidth(true));*/
        });
    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, a 'block' elemnt like a div will be as wide as its container.

When you set the position of an element to Absolute you take it out of the flow of the layout and remove the 'as wide as its container' property - it will shrink to contain its contents.

Since your images are the widest thing in there and they're floated, they end up being stacked vertically and the resulting width is 160px.

Maybe you can elaborate on your intent with the absolute positioning so we can help you more.

Answer (score -1):

I have the solution thanks God.
 
I need to change max-width: 690px to width: 690px, max-width: 100%; design will be correct.